# Why doesn't <form> submit even though it's recognized as closed?

Tags: html, forms, form-submit, submit-button

So I'm trying to build upon the following application, and previously I had this functional `<form>` tag below.

It's a bit of an eyesore but it's essentially just some `inputs` in a `table` for stylistic purposes, wrapped around by a `form`:

```
<form method='POST' action='http://localhost:8080/hw4/submission'
            form id="form" name="form">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Claim *</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="claim" name='claim' class="text" size="35" type="text" placeholder="What's your assertion?">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Argument/Evidence *</b>
        </td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="arg" name='arg' class="text" cols="37" rows="4" placeholder="Go ahead, prove yourself!" style="resize:none; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; font-size: 13px;"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px; color:#FF0099;x"> &lowast; - Required field
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <!-- Form submit -->
        <p><input type='button' value='Submit' style='width:100px' onclick='return checkFields();'></p></form>
```

`checkFields()` is a Javascript function that just checks for empty input fields, and if they are not all empty, it calls `document.getElementById("form").submit();`

When inspecting the source code, my browsers (Chrome, Firefox) would say the `<form>` tag was open, but yet it would still do the `POST` call without any problems.

I then tried to add an additional input field like so:

```
<form method='POST' action="http://localhost:8080/hw5/submission"
            id="form" name="form">
            <table width="550px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <b>Name</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="username" class="text" size="45" type="text" placeholder="This will display with your claim">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <b>Claim</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="claim" class="text" size="45" type="text" placeholder="What's your assertion?">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <b>Argument/Evidence</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="arg" class="text" cols="37" rows="2" placeholder="Go ahead, prove yourself!"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Form submit -->
            <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" style="width:100px" onclick="return checkFields();">
    </form>
```

Note all I really changed was I added `<input id="username">`. When inspecting the code in the browsers, it says the `<form>` is closed (though eclipse says it's not) and it won't submit.

I tried wrapping each `<input>` itself with `<form id="form"></form>`, which appeased eclipse's warnings, but in trying to output any of the request parameters, it'd return `NULL`.

I'm at my wits end trying to understand what's going on under the hood here.

Comment: Can you be absolutely sure (and double-check if you need to) that there are no other `<form>` tags in the HTML? Do a find within your editor for `"<form"` just to be sure :)

Comment: *just some `inputs` in a `table` for stylistic purposes* Nooooooo!

Comment: @GeoffJames Just double-checked for "<form," where there's one instance thereof. Also checked for "form" and they appear in the opening and closing tag. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Also forgot to mention (and you probably know this already): you shouldn't use a `<form>` within a `<form>`, like you mentioned as something you tried. Causes a whole heap of problems

Comment: @BenM Haha sorry if that was against convention. Wasn't sure how else to make the layout symmetric, if you have a better recommendation by all means. This is for a somewhat introductory class so we aren't really using anything aside from HTML and CSS on the layout/stylistic coding side.

Comment: @GeoffJames what I tried was<form id="form"> <input .../> </form> { ... more code ... } <form id="form"> <input... /> </form> to try to depreciate the eclipse warnings, but yeah even though that would submit the page the parameters weren't being communicated anyway. I was kind of finagling with stuff.

Comment: @itsamoniker -- ah, right. From the way you'd said "tried wrapping each input..." I thought you meant you'd put forms around each input, in situ inside the existing form :)

Comment: Unless my eyes are deceiving me... And I don't know how I didn't notice til now... Look at the second line at the top of your question. There seems to be a rogue `form` "attribute" at the start of the line (before `id="form"`). Is that any help?

Comment: @GeoffJames Yeah, I did notice the stray `form` attribute after submitting the question, but it actually didn't affect anything (huh). The first form I posted works, but the second one doesn't. That's what I'm trying to get to the bottom of.

Comment: Weird request: what happens if you change the second button's `onclick` to not return, but just call `checkFields()`? You might also want to prevent the default behaviour at the top of the method (am on phone, so not easy to type out - search "stop propagation" in your favourite search engine).

Comment: I don't know if the answer would be as simple as this; but try putting the `return checkFields()` call inside an `onsubmit` of the form, instead of the button (and I would also advise to change the button type to `submit`). Just ensure that your `checkFields()` returns `false` if it's invalid. I don't mean this to seem patronising at all, but take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp -- it's very useful, and where I just found that suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't use the Snippet, use the Plunker

There were some critical typos that brought everything down:

- Each `<form>` was broken into two lines, but it wouldn't matter if that was fixed...
- ...because each form had an extra word inside the tag: `form`
- A `color:#FF0099"` was followed by a `x;` that looks like a piece of `px`.

Added a few things:

- Each `<form>` has a functioning test server in `method` and `target` attribute pointing to...
- ...a new iframe. It's purpose is to display the data sent by the forms.
- Changed all `<input type='button'...>` to `<input type='submit'...>`. Now with real submit buttons you don't need any extra JS/jQ to submit a form anymore.

<kbd>**[PLUNKER](http://embed.plnkr.co/QHfXcBeS2pGlGMJEHWbT/)**</kbd>

#### SNIPPET

```html
<form method='POST' action='http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php/form1' id="form1" name="form1" target='win1'>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Claim *</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="claim1" name='claim1' class="text" size="35" type="text" placeholder="What's your assertion?">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Argument/Evidence *</b>
        </td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="arg1" name='arg1' class="text" cols="37" rows="4" placeholder="Go ahead, prove yourself!" style="resize:none; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; font-size: 13px;"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px; color:#FF0099"> &lowast; - Required field
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <!-- Form submit -->
        <p><input type='submit' style='width:100px'></p></form>
<iframe src='about:_blank' id='win1' name='win1' width='200' height='50px'></iframe>
<!--==================================================-->
<form method='POST' action='http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php/form2' id="form2" name="form2" target='win2'>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Claim *</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="claim2" name='claim2' class="text" size="35" type="text" placeholder="What's your assertion?">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Argument/Evidence *</b>
        </td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="arg2" name='arg2' class="text" cols="37" rows="4" placeholder="Go ahead, prove yourself!" style="resize:none; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; font-size: 13px;"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px; color:#FF0099"> &lowast; - Required field
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <!-- Form submit -->
        <p><input type='submit' style='width:100px'></p></form>
<iframe src='about:_blank' id='win2' name='win2' width='200' height='50px'></iframe>
<!--===================================================-->
<form method='POST' action="http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php/form3" id="form3" name="form3" target='win3'>
            <table width="550px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <b>Name</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="username3" class="text" size="45" type="text" placeholder="This will display with your claim">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <b>Claim</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="claim3" class="text" size="45" type="text" placeholder="What's your assertion?">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <b>Argument/Evidence</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="arg3" class="text" cols="37" rows="2" placeholder="Go ahead, prove yourself!"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Form submit -->
            <input id="submit3" type="submit" style="width:100px">
    </form>
<iframe src='about:_blank' id='win3' name='win3' width='200' height='50px'></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The typos you mentioned, which were in that first <form> version I had, actually didn't affect the functionality of the page. But thank you for pointing them out.

Comment: I used a <input button> instead of an <input submit> because I wanted to do some JS checks that would qualify whether to submit the form or not. If there's a better way to do that, I'm all ears but that's what I found to work. Also I'm a little confused why you introduced the use of an iframe. I guess I didn't mention the additional context, but anyway I'm posting the inputs to a servlet and after manipulating them with the servlet, having it redirect to a "results" page.

Comment: I have to admit, I was going to suggest using the buttons as type of `submit`; then I realised that there's the `onclick` and the method to validate and then submit the form. I'm pretty certain there are other validation methods that simply "plug in" to existing code (with proper `submit` buttons) that I've used before now. I'll have a mooch and see.

Comment: The iframe is to show that the form in fact does work, when I make a demo,  if at all possible I will not only have it functioning, I'll show you it's guts if it's possible. You didn't provide the JS, therefore onclick being a moot point.